# Analog of VBA`s FillBLOB in c# while inserting large string into ntext

Tags: c#, sql-server, vba

Im converting code from VBA into c# and it is all about creating looong string and inserting it into MSSQL ntext field, im not kinda sure about the string`s size, but it looks rather too long for me. In VBA code insert statement looks like this:

```
With rstFormat
    .AddNew
.Fields("field").Value      = b
.Fields("field2").Value     = "a"
FillBLOB .Fields("loongstring"), loongstring
```

So, i guess, FillBlob is a good idea, but how i can do the same with c#?

I am using ADO.NET.

Comment: There is no built-in function FillBlob in VBA. I suspect that this is a user function and the likely purpose is to insert blob data for an image or such like ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308042 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about assigning a string variable to the NTEXT parameter like this:

```
SqlCommand mySqlCommand_new;
mySqlCommand_new = SQLConnection.CreateCommand();
mySqlCommand_new.CommandText = "insert table (column) values(@text)";
mySqlCommand_new.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@text", SqlDbType.NText));
mySqlCommand_new.Parameters["@code"].Value = text;
mySqlCommand_new.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/2eee04ec-7510-42aa-97ea-8163b40c4c9b/

Comment: Thanks, but that is actually what I do, I thought there was some kind of magic behind VBA`s FillBlob.

Comment: Look uo FillBlob in the VBA code, find will work, there is some kind of magic, I suspect.